# Is there a open source database of licensed physicians in the US by state

Tags: data-request, medical, data.gov

I am creating a database of preferential physicians for special needs families - is there an open-source database of licensed physicians in the US by the state?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an official source then I can suggest you this site https://healthdata.gov/search/type/dataset. Here you can search physicians dataset of different states. By the way, you can also visit Kaggle in this regard.

Comment: Unfortunately that site has died or moved since then: "Page Not Found
We're really sorry, but the page you requested cannot be found."